# Return Text From Lookup Field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-button, lookup

I have a Javascript button that creates an Opportunity from a Case. One of the fields in the new Opportunity is a Contact lookup field that needs to be pre-populated with the Contact field on the Case. All works fine unless the Contact name contains an apostrophe, then the Javascript throws an error that I'm missing a ). Does anyone know how to get the text of the Contact field from the Case?  I tried using JSENCODE, but that end us returning the Contact ID.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/apex.js")}

var query = "SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Contact WHERE Id = '{!Case.ContactId}' limit 1";

var CName = sforce.connection.query(query);

ConName = CName.getArray("ConName");
console.log('###'+ConName);
var myCon1 = ConName[0].FirstName;

window.open('/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W='+myCon1+' '+myCon.LastName+'&ent=Opportunity');
```

Comment: John you will have to query the contact name since this is a related object's field that you are trying to access from the case object. Look for examples on how to query in javascript button and I am sure you will find tons of references eg:https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000htWHAAY

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code and it gives me an error:  "Cannot read property of "FirstName" undefined.  Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Do console.log('###'+ConName); under ConName= line, save the code and refresh your browser. Right click on your browser preferably chrome and see under console (2nd tab usually) what you see and paste the result in your original question

Comment: if you can post the query result and make sure data is coming back for the query, I can look from there why you are getting undefined for the query. also declare ConName, use Var ConName = CName.getArray("ConName"); it is a good practice to be strict mode compliant

Comment: connection.js:594 Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
send @ connection.js:594
sforce.SoapTransport.send @ connection.js:1013
sforce.Connection._invoke @ connection.js:1803
sforce.Connection.invoke @ connection.js:1742
sforce.Connection.query @ connection.js:1396
(anonymous) @ VM4854:6
(anonymous) @ 500a000001Kw7yF:470
loadScripts @ main.js:269
loadScripts @ main.js:269
loadScripts @ main.js:269
element.invokeAction @ 500a000001Kw7yF:466
window.invokeOnClickJS_00ba0000001EZXc @ 500a000001Kw7yF:474
onclick @ 500a000001Kw7yF:407

Comment: I changed the original code and added the error.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67072/discussion-between-rao-and-john-neilan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the issue is with your code

```
ConName = CName.getArray("ConName");
console.log('###'+ConName);
```

You are asking the system to getArray by name "ConName". when you query using sforce.connection you get the result bask in the following format

> $$$$${done:'true', queryLocator:null, records:{type:'Contact',
>   Id:null, FirstName:'test', LastName:'dasfsdfsd', }, size:'1', }

In the above response the only array you see is "records" so your CName,getArray("ConName") is coming back undefined because there is no array by name ConName.

**Solution:**

Change this to

```
 var ConName = CName.getArray("records");
```

Comment: @john most welcome